# How to properly separate MVVM code in my case?

Tags: android, mvvm

I just started learning MVVM and I have problem with some code. 
How to correctly separate this kind of code between View and ViewModel?

I also have question about differences between Presenter from MVP and ViewModel from MVVM. The main difference between that two classes is communication or there is something more? It seems to be same but I'm confused.

```
public class TaskFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "TaskFragment";

@Nullable
@BindView(R.id.floating_button) FloatingActionButton floatingButton;
@BindView(R.id.date_text) TextView dateText;
@BindView(R.id.time_text) TextView timeText;
@BindView(R.id.title_text) TextView titleText;
@BindView(R.id.save_button) Button saveButton;

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener;

Realm realm;
RealmHelper realmHelper;

String mText, mDate, mTime;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_fragment, container, false);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).hideFloatingActionButton();


    realmHelper = new RealmHelper(realm);
    Realm.init(getActivity());
    RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration
            .Builder()
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
    realm = Realm.getInstance(configuration);

    mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            month = month + 1;
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataSet: dd/mm/yyyy: " + year + "/" + month + "/" + dayOfMonth);
            String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            dateText.setText(date);
        }
    };

    mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onTimeSet: hh/mm: " + hourOfDay + "/" + minute);
            String time = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
            timeText.setText(time);
        }
    };

    return view;

}


@OnClick(R.id.date_text)
public void onClickDate() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth, mDateSetListener,
            year, month, day);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
}


@OnClick(R.id.time_text)
public void onClickTime() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hourOfDay = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth, mTimeSetListener,
            hourOfDay, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
}


@OnClick(R.id.save_button)
public void onClickSave() {
    mText = titleText.getText().toString();
    mDate = dateText.getText().toString();
    mTime = timeText.getText().toString();

    Task task = new Task();
    task.setText(mText);
    task.setDate(mDate);
    task.setTime(mTime);

    Log.d(TAG, "ON_CLICK_SAVE" + " / " + mText + " / " + mDate + " / " + mTime + " / " + getId());

    realmHelper = new RealmHelper(realm);
    realmHelper.saveTask(task);


    if(!mText.isEmpty() && !mDate.isEmpty() && !mTime.isEmpty()) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Task added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    titleText.setText("");
    dateText.setText("");
    timeText.setText("");
}


@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    realm.close();
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This looks like legit View class. I do not know what RealmConfiguration is, so maybe it could be moved to ViewModel. Basically ViewModel is responsible for all interfaces to access logic/business flow in Model. View is only reacting to ViewModel change. Here u could pass your data from textViews to ViewModel via ViewModelProviders.